# JavaScript & JQuery not alphabetizing list on certain devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I intend for this code to do:

- Alphabetize the list (from A->Z)

What happens instead:

The list is alphabetizing on my laptop but not on my iPhone. I also has to change the conditional in the JavaScript because the code kept defaulting to the else case. I'm not grasping exactly what the if statement is doing, so if someone could explain that, I would appreciate it greatly.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    var $sort = this;
    var $list = $('div.dropdown-content');
    var $listLi = $('a', $list);
    $listLi.sort(function (a, b) {
        var keyA = $(a).text();
        var keyB = $(b).text();
        if ($($sort).hasClass('asc')) {
            return (keyA > keyB) ? 1 : 0;
        } else {
            return (keyA > keyB) ? 1 : 0;
        }
    });
    $.each($listLi, function (index, row) {
        $list.append(row);
    });
});
```

HTML (for the relevant area):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>GeoMaps</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav navhome">
            <a href="">
                <h3 style="display:inline">GeoMaps</h3>
                <h6 style="display:inline">for use with AP® Human Geography</h6>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav" style="float:right"><a href="#maps">About</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown" style="float:right">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Maps</a>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
               <!--This list will be automatically alphabetized by JS-->
                <a href="#">East Asia</a>
                <a href="#">Oceania</a>
                <a href="#">Russia</a>
                <a href="#">Europe</a>
                <a href="#">South Asia</a>
                <a href="#">Southeast Asia</a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

This website is hosted on GitHub pages, if that makes a difference.

Comment: Note, `this` is `document` within `.ready()` handler.

Comment: @guest271314 What am I supposed to change then? This isn't entirely my code (tutorial).

Comment: I haven't used jQuery in a while, but this code seems like its appending a sorted list to the unsorted list. It doesn't appear to be replacing the original list.

Comment: @TomCoughlin Should I use something like list.replace then? And I'm confused as to why it's not in order on my iPhone but it is on my computer.

Comment: @Bora That portion does not appear to have an affect on result, as both `if` and `else` return same result.

Comment: @guest271314 Can you explain where this line is referencing to when it's searching for 'asc'?         `if ($($sort).hasClass('asc')) {`

Comment: @Bora I'm not too sure, I'd try removing the `if/else` block entirely, just return `(keyA > keyB) ? 1 : 0`

Comment: `$sort` is `document` defined at `var $sort = this`. `document` does not have `.className` property.

Comment: @TomCoughlin Thanks, I can see how that makes the code more efficient, but it didn't change the result on my phone.

Comment: @Bora Why are you sorting `.text()` instead of first character of `.text()`?

Comment: @guest271314 Forgive me, I'm still confused. I am not using a classname in any of those places, right? Or do you mean to say I need to get the classname out of here: `var $list = $('div.dropdown-content');
`

Comment: @guest271314 That's how the tutorial had it. Should I change it? And if so, to what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort by the first character of `.textContent` of `a` element

```js
$(function() {
  var $list = $("div.dropdown-content");
  $list.html(
    $("a", $list).sort(function(a, b) {
      return b.textContent[0] < a.textContent[0]
    })
  );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<ul>
<li class="dropdown" style="float:right">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Maps</a>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <!--This list should be automatically alphabetized by JS-->
    <a href="#">East Asia</a>
    <a href="#">Oceania</a>
    <a href="#">Russia</a>
    <a href="#">Europe</a>
    <a href="#">South Asia</a>
    <a href="#">Southeast Asia</a>
  </div>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It still won't work on my iPhone though... It's hosted at pwsh.github.io/geo-maps. What should I try? Could it possibly be a non-code issue?

Comment: _"It still won't work on my iPhone though"_ Have no experience with *phone. The approach at Answer should return expected result. No `<ul>` element appears at `html` at Question. Do you have a parent `<ul>` surrounding `<li>` elements at actual `html` `document` you are trying at?

Comment: I used a web proxy and it didn't work there either. I'm so lost. Would you mind taking a look at the repo? Sorry for the beginner questions. https://github.com/pwsh/geo-maps

Comment: Yes, I do have a <ul> surrounding <li>.

Comment: @Bora Repo is not mentioned at original Question, and should not be relevant to `html`, `javascript` at Question, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I modified my question to include the entirety of the HTML code. Today is my first day ever using JavaScript. I tried your code above, but I'm getting the same results.

Comment: Are expected results returned at stacksnippets?

Comment: Yes, snapsnippets has exactly what I'm looking for (w/o my CSS, off course).

Comment: I think I discovered the issue. I had previously tweaked a setting with my mobile browser. Thank you for your help! The simplified version is much easier to understand and thoroughly aids my learning process.